# How can you relate structural forces to load factors and inertia force

Tags: aircraft-structures

Our professor in aircraft structures asked us to research how can you relate structural forces to load factors and inertia forces and i dont have a clue. Help

Comment: Start with $F=ma$ and then come back when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

F=ma is a great place to start!  The other one is torque = force x lever arm length.

One might start by considering what needs to be built, a jet fighter or a recreational biplane.
Limiting factors eventually are pilot comfort, speed, and manuverability.  You build a flight envelope profile:  how fast, how slow, how high, (we all get) how low.

From these parameters (and with the help of more mathmaticly oriented colleagues found here) we now set maximum loads on the aircraft, usually at maximum speed and mauverability.

Notice that inertia is a function of mass.  F=ma. a=F/m.  If it is heavier the acceleration
is less.  This would work into roll rates with heavier wing tips.

Torque would work into control surface area and distance from CG, as well as weight distribution.

Structural forces must be sufficient (safety margins are suggested) to meet all load forces.

Before wading into the Math, I would present the design application and determine reasonable limits and safety margins.

In the real world there is nothing wrong with forming a team to solve these issues.